# Jquery input validation dependent on checkbox value

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to avoid a validation mess and using inline validation. I have a checkbox that is followed by three input boxes. If the checkbox is checked, the input fields have to become "required". Else not.

Here is the code:

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="vi" name="vi" checked="checked">
            I have Apple
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Apple condition?</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="appleCond" validate="required:'checkbox[name=vi][value=Yes]:checked'">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sourced from ?</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="appleSource" validate="required:'checkbox[name=vi][value=Yes]:checked'">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control" id="appleQuantity" validate="required:'checkbox[name=vi][value=Yes]:checked'">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am sure I am doing something wrong with the syntax. Can anyone point the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Well This can be done as follows. Default make the checkbox as unchecked and write following `jquery` to it

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var atLeastOneIsChecked = $('input[name="vi"]:checked').length > 0;
       if(atLeastOneIsChecked){
        $("input").attr("required", "true");
      }
    else {
        // else do what you need to do with this case
    }
});
```

Comment: There are 32 other input boxes that are not linked to this checkbox. So     if(atLeastOneIsChecked){
        $("input").attr("required", "true");
      } will not work.

Comment: So just make changes to the question. will try to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Give class to other div's apart from checkbox div,say "check_1".

html:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="vi" name="vi" />
            I have Apple
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 check_1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Apple condition?</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control  input_val" id="appleCond" validate="required"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 check_1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Sourced from ?</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control input_val" id="appleSource" validate="required"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 check_1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Quantity</label> 
        <input type="input" class="form-control  input_val" id="appleQuantity" validate="required"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="button_submit"/>
</div>
```

js:

```
var check_box=0;
$(".check_1").hide();


 $('#button_submit').click(function() {
    if(check_box==true)
    {

        $(".input_val").prop('required',true);



    }
     else
     {
        // code when checkbox not selected
     }

});


$('input[name="vi"]').click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
           $(".check_1").show();
            check_box=true;
        }
    else{
             $(".check_1").hide();
            check_box=false;
    }
});
```

[check it here](https://jsfiddle.net/2f5zgtdm/2/)

Comment: I need the text boxes to be validated when the form is submitted. How does the above solution relate to it?